# SDL Tridion 2012 UI - Error when updating preview and publishing

Tags: tridion, tridion-2011

I am installing the cd_preview_webservice on Tomcat which also has applications for the staging web site (to be use for the UI) and the cd_upload (which deploys to the web site) installed.

When I click the 'Update Preview' or 'Finish Editing' I get the following error:

com/tridion/deployer/TCDLTransformer

Also this send the tomcat process to 100% CPU usage.

I have re-read the instructions and I can not see where I have made my mistake. Any help much appreciated.

Thanks
Mark

I have done some more digging and it would appear that I get a session preview Id saved into the database in the 'PREVIEW_SESSIONS' table but others are empty. Which I find odd.

I also found that the following web service call 'http://bbtrid04/WebUI/Models/SiteEdit/Services/Services.svc/GetPreviewToken' receives the following response:

{"ExceptionDetail":null,"ExceptionType":null,"Message":"PermGen space","StackTrace":null}

and the localhost log file contains the following error:

```
07-Aug-2012 17:34:04 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet httpupload threw exception
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space
    at org.apache.commons.fileupload.disk.DiskFileItemFactory.createItem(DiskFileItemFactory.java:199)
    at org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadBase.parseRequest(FileUploadBase.java:361)
    at org.apache.commons.fileupload.servlet.ServletFileUpload.parseRequest(ServletFileUpload.java:126)
    at com.tridion.transport.HTTPSReceiverServlet.handleUpload(HTTPSReceiverServlet.java:233)
    at com.tridion.transport.HTTPSReceiverServlet.doPost(HTTPSReceiverServlet.java:108)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:859)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:588)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
07-Aug-2012 17:34:05 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet httpupload threw exception
java.lang.VerifyError: (class: org/apache/commons/fileupload/disk/DiskFileItem, method: getUniqueId signature: ()Ljava/lang/String;) Illegal constant pool index
    at org.apache.commons.fileupload.disk.DiskFileItemFactory.createItem(DiskFileItemFactory.java:199)
    at org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadBase.parseRequest(FileUploadBase.java:361)
    at org.apache.commons.fileupload.servlet.ServletFileUpload.parseRequest(ServletFileUpload.java:126)
    at com.tridion.transport.HTTPSReceiverServlet.handleUpload(HTTPSReceiverServlet.java:233)
    at com.tridion.transport.HTTPSReceiverServlet.doPost(HTTPSReceiverServlet.java:108)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:859)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:588)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Hey Mark. Can you check that error message again? Right now it only shows a class name, which sounds unusually incomplete to me.

Comment: Of course will check now. I was also confused by the error message.

Comment: Well, it that is indeed all it says it is most likely a "class loading issue". Unfortunately that is as vague as I can make it, so I hope someone else in that case will have a better clue.

Comment: Hi Frank. Thanks for your help. I have done some more digging and have turn up a few more clues. Any ideas? Mark

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When the JVM loads classes it puts them into the PermGen space of its heap, which defaults to 64MB.

The stack trace you showed is a dead give-away that your JVM is loading more classes than it has space for and would definitely explain its complaint about not finding the TCDLTransformer.

I typically have a `-XX:MaxPermSize=256m` in my `setenv.bat` to ensure there is enough space. Depending on how you start your Tomcat, you may need to put it there or in the service runner parameters.

Comment: Increasing the size of MaxPermSize did indeed remove the error from the logs. Unfortunately the same error persists in the UI. When update the preview or finishing editing I get the following error when the below is requested: Request: bbtrid04/WebUI/Models/SiteEdit/Services/Services.svc/… Response: {"ExceptionDetail":null,"ExceptionType":null,"Message":"com\/tridion\/deployer\/‌​TCDLTransformer","StackTrace":null}

Comment: I also found to that I had to the following jars into the cd_preview_webservice application from the cd_upload application: cd_deployer.jar, cd_upload.jar, commons-fileupload.jar, commons-io.jar. This removed the TCDLDeployer error.